# Does power bi web support OData as data source?

Tags: powerbi, odata

As per my reading over microsoft documents, power bi desktop do support data feed
from OData, but I am not sure does the Power bi web support OData data feed.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all supported datasource here. Check column "Connect and refresh from service" + "Gateway". For OData only, "DirectQuery / Live Connection" is not supported.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/power-bi-data-sources#data-sources-m-o

Comment: Thanks for response and its quite useful. I am new to Power bi and doing some exploration. What I have understood is that OData can be used as datasource in power bi desktop and "Connect and refresh from service". Does "Connect and refresh from service" means Power bi web ?

Comment: Yes that's right